# No realiza salto de línea en el fichero txt

Tags: php, session

Tengo un código en el que guardo un log con el registor de actividad de los usuarios en mi intranet, y quiero que cada usuario este en una línea diferente pero no realiza el salto de línea.

```
$nowtimename = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
$fp = fopen ("logs.txt", "a");
fwrite ($fp, $_SESSION["usuario"]);
fwrite ($fp, ";");
fwrite ($fp, $_SESSION["privilegio"]);
fwrite ($fp, ";");
fwrite ($fp, $nowtimename);
fwrite ($fp, \n);
fclose ($fp);
?>

$nowtimename = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
$fp = fopen ("logs.txt", "a");
fwrite ($fp, $_SESSION["usuario"]);
fwrite ($fp, ";");
fwrite ($fp, $_SESSION["privilegio"]);
fwrite ($fp, ";");
fwrite ($fp, $nowtimename);
fwrite ($fp, "\n");
fclose ($fp);
?>
```

Lo probe de esas dos maneras y no me funciona.

Comment: Estás en windows o linux? En windows se sigue usando [CRLF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRLF) como marcador de nueva línea.

Comment: Lo pruebo en windows pero luego lo pasare a un CentOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes escribir el `\n` entre comillas simples y no con dobles:

```
fwrite ($fp, '\n');
```

Si con esto no te funciona prueba con el `PHP_EOL`, te dejo el [manual](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Perfecto con `PHP_EOL` Muchisimas gracias. `fwrite ($fp, $localIP . PHP_EOL);`

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite ($fp, "\n");
```

Tienes que hacerlo con comillas dobles, con comillas simples no funciona.

Comment: Por favor, añade una descripción un poco más elaborada del porque de tu respuesta. Ha sido reportada como baja calidad por tu extensión y contenido.

Comment: El usuario lo tiene ya puesto con comillas dobles y no parece funcionar. ¿Seguro que ésta es la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("./txt/datos.txt", "a+") or die("Problemas con el archivo");
    fwrite($file, $_POST['nomina'].',');
    fwrite($file, $_POST['nombre'].',');
    fwrite($file, $_POST['sueldo']."\r");
    echo("Archivo generado correctamente");
?>
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto con las comillas dobles